# Reading user selection from Django 1.5 template without using Models

Tags: python, html, django, templates, html-select

Im using **Python27** with **Django 1.5**.

i have been scowering the internet for hours without success. Is there a way to capture what the user has selected from a dropdown listbox in a template without using Models? Im looking for a direct way to read some sort of var into code in views.py.

*example.html*

```
<select name="num_select">
    <option value="0">-----</option>
    <option value="10">1 - 10</option>
    <option value="20">10 - 20</option>
    <option value="30">20 - 30</option>
    <option value="40">30 - 40</option>
    <option value="all">all</option>
</select>
```

which every option i select I want to pass the value to a var in my views.py

*views.py*

```
def my_view(request):
    ...
    num_select = forms.????.get['num_select']
    ...
    return blah blah....
```

I hope i have provided enough details for you to assist me. Not sure what else i can add. I have been going through pages of docs without success. I know how to get vars from views.py to html templates, but not vise-versa.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: use `print(forms)` or even `print( dir(forms) )` to see what you have in forms.

Comment: thanks for the reply. not sure how to use this to get what i need. by the looks of below, I think i should be good. thanks!

Comment: `dir(object)` returns all functions and variables in object - it is usefull if you don't remeber names and don't use IDE with autocomplete.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you don't need models for this at all, what you need is a simple [django form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/).

```
CHOICES = ( (1,"10"), (2,"20"), ...)

class MyForm(forms.form):
    ...
    num_select = forms.ChoiceField(choices = CHOICES)
    ...
```

Then in your view

```
from myapp.forms import MyForm

def my_view(request):

    if request.method = 'POST':
        form = MyForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
              num_select = form.cleaned_data['num_select']
```

This is of course a rather stripped down version of it, for additional information refer to the link above.

If you don't want to use a form either, you can just access `request.POST` directly, but then what's the point of using Django? you might as well use PHP

Comment: dah! was almost there. looks like this is just what i need. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can read raw form data by using `HttpRequest.POST` API

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST

It's a dictionary-like object containing all given HTTP POST parameters.

You can just `request.POST['num_select']`

Remember to include `if request.method == 'POST':` before using `request.POST`

Comment: this looks interesting...ill definitely play around with this. thanks!